# I need to trigger onChange event when checked radio button is clicked again

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a html page with radio button. In my javascript file I have written event listener for that radio button. It is a "change" event listener. When radio button selection changed event listener will triggered properly but what i need is same change event should trigger when ever user clicks the checked radio button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `change` event is not the best for that behaviour.. What about `click` event and ask if it's checked? If you need more help, see a few lines of code will be awesome.

Comment: I am trying to fix a bug in some one else program. so, I can't able to change the event. It affects lot of functions. thats why i am trying to trigger the same event when the checked radio button is clicked again.

Comment: I understand your issue but I'm almost sure that there is not a way to force that the event is being triggered alone again. In fact, I'm not talking about replacing the event, just add a new one where you can add new code or call the old one if the radio is checked. it could be a workaround...

Comment: @dev-cc thank you I will try the same